# MySQL extract HOUR from DATETIME and express in AM/PM

Tags: mysql, datetime-format

sql newbie here. I googled around for a quick solution to this, but failed to find it.

I have a field that is a `DATETIME`, for e.g., `2014/06/19 15:07:37`. I just need to extract the HOUR and express it in AM/PM, i.e., the above result should read `3pm`.

I have tried `DATE_FORMAT(HOUR(date_field), %r)` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date_format()` expects a date. `hour` returns an int. You just need

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%l%p')
```

note that `%r` is a full time, `hh:mm:ss`, not just the hour.

Comment: can you explain the `'%l%p'` part?

Comment: @eager_learner313 See the MySQL manual, on `DATE_FORMAT`. The manual is worth reading, and you don't have to ask then...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse why don't you just tell me you don't like me instead of trolling on my posts and down voting? Even if I do ask, what's wrong with that? You don't have to answer it, you know? There are much nicer and encouraging people here.

Comment: @eager_learner313: no, RTFM is an entirely appropriate response. We're here to help, not find documentation references for you. Why not take your username to heart and actually TRY to learn? Instead of wanting US to look up the man page for you, why don't you just go look at it yourself? You'll actually learn something by seeing what's available.

Comment: @MarcB: point taken; however, there are times the FMs are written as well they should be. At times, it's a faster process to ask than to go through the 1343242 pages. RTFM is NOT always the right response. I find it offensive that you ASSUME that I am NOT trying to learn. Everyone learns in a different way-- some people have 15000 hours to spend; others not so much. When I asked the question, I did go through the manual, but was pressed for time; the answer actually came up quickly which helped me to solve a bigger problem. Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

You need `TIME_FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), "%h%p");
```